# How to merge two datasets in R where one dataset has geometry variable

Tags: r, merge

I want to merge two datasets where one of them has column with geometry (polygons) data. 
`Geom` data looks like this:

```
0xE8200000010431123000556D272278CC2640331EB53791A14740ABC99B2F71............
```

Unfortunately, the data are defined by R as numeric infinite so merging doesn't work.
Well, I looked around for solutions but this issue is obviosly very rare.
I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: can you give example of the data?

Comment: Do you use a specific package to manage your polygons data ? What is the class of `Geom` ?

Comment: here are header and a row of dataframe. another one has similar data without geom. HEADER:ZSP_ID STN B1 ST GC  ZP City  ZSPID EZ  geom
ROW:70101000 602001 Innenstadt Innenstadt 70101 0 Innsbruck 70101000 1 0xE8200000010431123000556D272278C…….                                                                                          The class is SQL geometry class. I do not use any package for merging.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that you didn't mention what class your data are (`class(data$Geom)`), I guess one idea would be to convert this column to character and then calculate a crc32 hash (using function `digest()` in package `digest`):

```
data$crc <- sapply(as.character(data$Geom), digest, algo="crc32")
```

Then you could try merging by this column.

Comment: class is numeric with Inf values. I use diggest package usually for semantic filtering. converting to hash is one way but how can I get the values back to geom since I have to execute it finaly in Visual basic studio. my problem is probably the length of the vaulues (around 1200 characters per geom-value)

Comment: I'll try it anyway.forgot that diggest generates separate column. tnx